# Delphi - get same field pointer with RTTI e Addr

Tags: delphi, rtti

Can I get the same pointer of a Field with RTTI  and Addr(Field)?

eg:

TSomeClass

private 
FSomeField: Integer;

...

1) MyPointer = Addr(FSomeField) >> $12345

2) RTTI pointer from SameField >> $12345

Comment: I don't understand. What exactly does your code have as input to your desired function

Comment: I want to get the pointer of a field with RTTI in certain function and the same pointer with Addr (Field) outside the function.

Comment: Could you please read my comment again. Perhaps you could show a function declaration whose body we can fill out.

Comment: Please stop adding information in comments, and [edit] your question to add the information there instead where it can be seen. Hiding details in comment clutter is not useful, and your question as stated is not clear enough to be of use to future readers here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually all you need is to get RTTI field offset (`TRttiField.Offset`) and add it to initial object address (instance address).

```
type
    TTest = class(TObject)
      private
        FInt : integer;
        FString : string;
        FBool : boolean;
    end;

var t : TTest;
    ctx : TRttiContext;
    f : TRttiField;
begin

    t := TTest.Create();
    try
        writeln(Format('FInt: %p',[@t.FInt]));
        writeln(Format('FString: %p', [addr(t.FString)]));
        writeln(Format('FBool: %p', [@t.FBool]));

        writeln('--------------');
        //field address using rtti
        ctx := TRttiContext.Create();
        try
            for f in ctx.GetType(t.ClassType).GetFields() do begin
                writeln(Format('%s: %8x', [f.Name, NativeInt(t) + f.Offset]));
            end;
        finally
            ctx.Free();
        end;

    finally
        t.Free();
    end;
    readln;
end.
```